# Comment « à » et « même » se sont-ils combinés pour signifier « en plein dans » ?

Tags: étymologie, indications-de-lieu, locutions

> [Larousse](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/french/m%C3%AAme/50392/locution?q=meme#16001768) À même quelque chose, sans intermédiaire, sans interposition de quoi que ce soit :
>   *Coucher à même le sol* ;
>   dans le vif, en plein dans quelque chose : *Des escaliers taillés à même le roc.*

En vain, j'ai tâché de recourir à l'étymologie de [même (adverbe)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/m%C3%AAme), dont je cite la version anglaise, car la version française est moins détaillée:

> From Middle French [mesme](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mesme#Middle_French), from Old French [mesme](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mesme#Old_French), earlier meïsme,
>   from Vulgar Latin *metipsimus, from -met + ipse + -issimus.
>   Cognates include Spanish mismo, Portuguese mesmo and Italian medesimo.

Answer (score 2):

Selon le Robert :

MÊME : adjectif, pronom et adverbe - *Mesme* 1271 ; *medisme* fin XIe puis *meïsme* ; latin populaire *metipsimus*, superlatif de *metipse*, latin ***edometipse***  « ***moi-même en personne*** ».

L'origine latine éclaire l'usage :

- À même le sol --> sur le sol lui-même (donc si c'est sur lui, c'est nulle autre part ; cela ne peut être ailleurs que sur le sol).
- À même le roc --> creusé dans le roc lui-même (et non pas sur ce qui peut le recouvrir)